# Want to open FB.Connect.streamPublish in a popup

Tags: facebook

I have been trying to make the Publish Stream preview modal that appears when i click on Publish Button, to appear in a pop window instead of a javascript modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you might go:

1: Create a html page
 2: Put all your FB publish stream code in above created page
 3: Use the **[window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)** with the path to above created page to it in popup window.

**Example:**

```
  <a href="#" onclick="window.open('popup.html', 'win', 'toolbar=0, menubar=0'); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback for your FB.ensureInit, add this:

```
FB.Connect.get_status().waitUntilReady(function(status)
{
    FB.Connect._openFeedDialogIframe = function(b, a, f)
    {
        FB.Connect._openFeedDialogWindow(b, a, f);
    };
});
```

This will cause the call to _openFeedDialogIframe to actually call _openFeedDialogWindow, so your feed dialog will be in a popup instead of in an iframe.

Good luck!